# How to grab label value from checked option with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

Im trying to grab value from label checkbox:checked.

I have created this function

```
 var levels = $('input[name=form[radio1]]:checked + label').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
$('input#radio1_val').val(levels);
```

and simple html

```
<input type="radio" id="radio14" value="150" name="form[radio1]">
<label for="radio14">Create simple static website</label>
```

But is does not seem to work.

Any ideas please?

Many thanks in advance

Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have works, it just needs a tweak like this:

```
var levels = $('input:checked + label').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xrdNt/).  [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) afterwards just returns the base array afterwards...I think your root issue is you're declaring `radio1_val` but setting `levels`.

Comment: radio1_val was completely from out of space. Although still having a problem. your function works perfectly, but when I'll add group name it still not giving me results for checked box. Any idea why this is not happening?. Changed my original post

Comment: @Dom - It *should* be: `$('input[name="form[radio1]"]:checked + label')`, but what you have works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xrdNt/1/ which browser is giving you issues?

Comment: it's FF and to be honest I didn't test it for any other just yet. Can I meet some difficulties with different browsers?

Comment: @Dom - You *shouldn't* if it's quoted, but if you do have problems link me the page here and I'll take a look...out of town this weekend but I'll check it out as soon as I'm back